# Magento redirect to order view

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to redirect user from my backend module to admin/order_sale/view, but i cant. When i use :

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("admin/sales_order/view", array('id'=>'1')));
```

Magento is cutting of 'admin' from URL so it looks like:

```
http://magento1702.local/index.php//sales_order/view/id/1/key/fdb6089cf1e5cd77f85f085def1a013a/
```

and i get 404 page.
Any idea how to redirect to admin module in magento way?

Comment: The first parameter to getUrl is the path.  The first part of the path is the 'route name'.  In the case on a backend module living under /admin (or whatever you changed admin to be), you would use the route name of 'adminhtml'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried **adminhtml** instead of **admin**?

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view", array('order_id'=>'1')));
```

Answer (score 7):

I think what you are looking for is adminhtml.

`Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("*/sales_order/view", array('order_id'=>'1'))`

**NB**: The param in 1.7 at least is order_id, rather than id. Not sure if this was different in older versions.

Comment: Yep, thank you. And you are right about order_id, i think in prev versions was the same :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are running into this issue is because of the  way you create your admin module

Take a look at this http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-admin-form/

Take a look at (note after="Mage_Adminhtml")

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <turnkeye_adminform after="Mage_Adminhtml">Turnkeye_Adminform_Adminhtml</turnkeye_adminform>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Once you update your code then you can do

`$this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order_id));`